# How to enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb

I have disabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` by using `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`. Now I want to restore the default settings.

Is it possible to enable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in MySQL again?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check this link: https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-turn-off-only-full-group-by.html

Comment: You know that disabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` might result in **invalid** query results right?? When you are using `GROUP BY` in a invalid way

Answer (score 16):

To avoid problems with other configurations, use CONCAT:

```sql
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Laravel, you could do this on runtime instead of making a global setting

```
//disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
DB::statement("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));");

//Your SQL goes here - The one throwing the error (:

//re-able ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
DB::statement("SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'));");
```