# Mysql getting only 1 result, rather than multiple

Tags: mysql

Short setup

[image]

consider the following.

```
SELECT forum_category.groupid, 
       forum_category.categoryid, 
       forum_category.categoryname, 
       forum_category.categorydescription, 
       forum_category.category_url, 
       forum_category.accesslevel ,
COUNT(DISTINCT forum_topic.topicid) AS topics , 
COUNT(DISTINCT forum_post.postid) AS posts 
FROM forum_category 
INNER JOIN forum_topic ON forum_topic.categoryid=forum_category.categoryid 
INNER JOIN forum_post ON forum_post.topicid=forum_topic.topicid 
WHERE groupid = 1
```

result

[image]

This gives me actually one result, while i expect multiple rows (in this case 2) to come back. What am I missing here?

Comment: Use aggregate function without group by clause..that's why you get one row

Comment: With just thoses informations, i’d say this is because the `INNER JOIN` are filtering the other result, but I cannot be sure since I don’t know what’s in the `forum_topic` and `forum_post` tables.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on that? I tried to use the group by `groupid`,  but wont buldge.

Comment: please provide table structure with sample data

Comment: @Joyescat I updated the question with the neccessairy tables

Comment: Basically, you get strange results because your query is invalid. MySQL has a special mode that allows that query anyway. Please [enable the `only_full_group_by` -mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55674941) and check [What are the benefits of only_full_group_by mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45484068).

Comment: About your problem, Rahul mentioned it in the first comment: `count()` will group your results to one row (same as, in your case, `group by groupid`: one row per groupid, you have one groupid, so you are expected to get one row). Please show the expected result for us to understand what you want (maybe try `group by forum_category.categoryid`?).

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks, that was the direction i needed. Had no idea i had to use `group by` in order to get this right. Indeed if use the `categoryid` for grouping i get the result i needed.