# Join tables on different cases for columns

Tags: sql, mysql

i declared my table's database to be clear

```html
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
objects
<table border='1'>
  <th>
    <td style='background:red'>ID (pk)</td>
    <td>is_rel_strg</td>
  </th>
</table>
   
<BR> strg_catgs
<BR> CatID in this table can be repeated with many elemID
<table border='1'>
  <th>
    <td style='background:red'>catID</td>
    <td style='background:gold'>elemID</td>
    <td>Disrate</td>
  </th>
</table>
<BR> strg_op
<table border='1'>
  <th>
    <td style='background:gold'>elemID</td>
    <td>opvalue</td>
    <td>opcost</td>
  </th>
</table>

<BR> strg
<table border='1'>
  <th>
    <td style='background:gold'>elemID (pk)</td>
    <td>name</td>

  </th>
</table>
```

How can I replace this 14 value with objects.ID and get result foll all these rows

```
SELECT SUM(t.totalcost) AS totalcost ,objects.ID  
FROM (
    select sum(strg_op.opcost) / sum(strg_op.opvalue * 1000) * strg_catgs.Disrate as totalcost 
    from strg_catgs  
    inner join strg_op  on strg_op.ElemID = strg_catgs.elemID  
        and strg_catgs.elemID = ( 
            SELECT strg_catgs.elemID 
            WHERE strg_catgs.catID =14 )  
        and strg_catgs.catID = 14 and strg_catgs.descr = "cwe"
    group by strg_catgs.elemID  
) AS t 
INNER JOIN objects ON objects.ID IN (
        select objects.ID 
        from objects 
        where objects.is_rel_strg>=1
    ) 
GROUP BY objects.ID
```

result be like

| totalcost | objects.ID |
| --- | --- |
| 23.4406137 | 31 |
| 23.4406137 | 2 |

All total cost values are same cause only catID which =14 has been selected

I tried this but I am getting wrong values.
What I desire Column which called totalcost  it's values changes when objects.ID change so i get all totalcost for all Objects.ID

```
SELECT SUM(t.totalcost) AS totalcost ,objects.ID  
FROM (
    select sum(strg_op.opcost)/ sum(strg_op.opvalue * 1000) * strg_catgs.Disrate as totalcost 
    from objects
    inner join strg_catgs  
    inner join strg_op  on strg_op.ElemID = strg_catgs.elemID  
        and strg_catgs.elemID =( 
           SELECT strg_catgs.elemID 
           WHERE strg_catgs.catID =objects.ID
        )  and strg_catgs.catID = objects.ID 
          and strg_catgs.descr = "cwe" 
          and objects.ID IN(Select objects.ID from objects where is_rel_strg>=1)
    group by strg_catgs.elemID  
) AS t 
INNER JOIN objects ON objects.ID IN (
        select objects.ID 
        from objects 
        where objects.is_rel_strg>=1
) GROUP BY objects.ID
```

Comment: See how much easier this is when you take just a few moments to format the code? Now you can easily spot the missing `FROM` clause.

Comment: sorry  i am new member here i am trying to format the code as i can to be clear

Comment: Why are you selecting `objects.ID` but not using that in the group by clause? (instead you group by `objects.descr` - this indicates to me that you do not have **only_full_group_by** on - and this leads to all sorts of anomalies. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57541786/2067753

Comment: @PaulMaxwell i have tried this changed it to Group By Objects.ID but still give me wrong result

Comment: There isn't any true relationship between table objects and any other table in your queries - and that is why it isn't working as expected. Is there a column in the objects table that jons to  strg_catgs, or to strg_op?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell there is relation ship between objects and strg_catgs , column CatID which in strg_catgs table = ID Column  Which in objects table

Comment: yes, sorry your query is confusing to me I'm afraid, but I had found those joins - more to come later.

Comment: Was able to suggest an answer. In future questions would you please provide **1** "sample data" and **2** the "expected result". This way we can test any proposed solution(s).

Answer (score 0):

The objective is to get costs per an object_id which is in the objects table, but you only need some of the rows so you also need to apply a filter. So I would expect the basic query structure to be like this:

```
SELECT object_id
FROM objects
WHERE objects.is_rel_strg >= 1
```

Now, with that basic query structure in place we can add the totalcost calculation in a sub-query:

```
SELECT objects.ID, t.totalcost
FROM objects
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT strg_catgs.catID, SUM(strg_op.opcost)/ SUM(strg_op.opvalue * 1000) * strg_catgs.Disrate as totalcost 
    FROM strg_catgs  
    INNER JOIN strg_op ON strg_op.ElemID = strg_catgs.elemID  
    WHERE strg_catgs.descr = "cwe"
    GROUP BY strg_catgs.catID
    ) AS t ON t.catID = objects.ID
WHERE objects.is_rel_strg >= 1
```

**nb** as there is no provided sample data this is untested and may still be incomplete

Comment: result still not as i desire , it gets all objects.ID but totalcost result not right , look objects table contains 2 columns (ID,is_rel_strg) objects table for products and strg_catgs contains 3 columns (catID,elemID,Disrate) catID which in objects ID and elemID itis in another table called strg  and strg_op contains 1 column (elemID) which also refer to strg table (ID)

Comment: Without DATA to test with there really isn't much point trying to describe the results that only you can see. Testing SQL requires data.

Comment: i declared the tables

Comment: I have no idea what that means, and what I now see in the question does not help me to help you.  Read this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ... a reminder I stated this under your question **please provide 1 "sample data" and 2 the "expected result". This way we can test any proposed solution(s).**