# join with sum case and group by in two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, sum, group

[image]

[image]

Result ----

[image]

but right total_used_reward is -275

My sql query :

```
SELECT ure.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(ure.id)) as total_referrer, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN uar.txn_type=1 THEN uar.reward ELSE 0 END) as total_used_reward 
FROM user_refer_earn ure 
JOIN user_activity_rewards uar ON uar.user_id = ure.code_owner 
WHERE ure.code_owner = 1 
GROUP BY ure.code_owner
```

right total_used_reward is -275

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: You also haven’t asked a question

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: Common join multiplying. Aggregate firstly, then join.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ - here used to count _distinct values_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT ure.id)` to make code clearer.

Comment: Your query is invalid and expected to raise an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674941/how-to-enable-only-full-group-by-in-mysql