I don't understand how to fetch number of policies against a customer
I have a table in which I am saving the policy ids and have another table in which i am saving all the customers mapped to that policy
When I have performed inner join between two tables I am getting the data in the below format



Policy Id
Customer




1
A


1
B


1
C


2
A


2
B



I can see in above data that Customer A has 2 policies, Customer B has 2 policies and Customer C has 1 policy
I have tried to write the query
select
  CustomerName,
  COUNT(policyid) as PolicyCount
from Dummy
group by
  clientId,
  policyid

Please see the output here
I have mentioned Customer A, B and C instead of  1 ,2 and 3
Output should be like



Customer
Policy Count




A
2


B
2


C
1



Please help me here how we can achieve it via query

Seeing sample data from both tables would be better than you listing the output of some mysterious query. But given the information and no idea what your tables look like, you could simply do this: select customer, count(distinct policy_id) as policy_count from (your mysterious query) group by customer. But I'm sure there's a better way, but you need to provide sample data from both tables.

You need GROUP BY CustomerName instead. I doubt your query even runs. You must group by the non-aggregate fields in the query, and you do not group by the aggregate fields.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674941/how-to-enable-only-full-group-by-in-mysql

The issue with your query is that you are grouping by both clientId and policyId hence each unique combination of clientId and policyId is treated as a separate group causing each row to be counted individually. You should instead group by customer to get the count of unique policyId
SELECT Customer,COUNT(DISTINCT PolicyId) AS PolicyCount
FROM Dummy
GROUP BY Customer;


Your query probably doesn't even execute. You are surely getting the following error message when running the query:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Column 'CustomerName' is invalid
in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
function or the GROUP BY clause.

You must group by the non-aggregate columns, and you do not group by the aggregate columns.
Here is the query you want:
DECLARE @PolicyCustomers TABLE (PolicyID INT, CustomerName NVARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO @PolicyCustomers (PolicyID, CustomerName)
VALUES (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B')

SELECT
    pc.CustomerName,
    COUNT(pc.PolicyID) AS PolicyCount
FROM
    @PolicyCustomers pc
GROUP BY
    pc.CustomerName
ORDER BY
    pc.CustomerName

Query results:



CustomerName
PolicyCount




A
2


B
2


C
1




OP's platform is probably MySQL where that kind of query is allowed.
