Write a query to select the amount of sales by country. Order the result by descending amount
I've been required while online self learning to do as title shows.
this is the info of the quesion:
Accounting
Instruction
Write a query to select the amount of sales by country. Order the result by descending amount.
Produce exactly two columns with the country code and the sales amount, as shown in the example below. Column aliases are not important.
Example
| country || total |
--------------------
FR           318421.25
IT           74757.74
ES           65175.77

This is what I tried (tried multiple ways)
SELECT users.country as 'Country', SUM(products.price * order_items.quantity) as 'Total Sales'
FROM users
INNER JOIN order_items ON users.id = order_items.order_id
INNER JOIN products ON order_items.product_id = products.id
ORDER BY users.country DESC;

And I get this result, but im supposed to get the other countries as well, not just DE.
Country || Total Sales
DE          363282.61

Any help appreciated, thank you.

You'd add GROUP BY with proper expression.

Please don’t use images of data, use editable text formatted as tables - so your data is copyable

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@NickW and Ken White, thanks I edited, hopefully better now.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674941/how-to-enable-only-full-group-by-in-mysql

@Akina thanks, i tried group by before but my inner joins were incorrect when i tried, now it works if i add order by after group by :)

@jarlh thanks, this might be helpful for me in the future

Here's the working solution thanks to akina:
SELECT users.country as 'Country', SUM(products.price * order_items.quantity) as Total_Sales 
FROM users INNER JOIN order_items ON users.id = order_items.order_id 
INNER JOIN products ON order_items.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY users.country
ORDER BY Total_Sales DESC;


try this
SELECT users.country as 'Country', SUM(products.price * order_items.quantity) as 'Total Sales'
FROM users
LEFT JOIN order_items ON users.id = order_items.order_id
LEFT JOIN products ON order_items.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY users.country
ORDER BY users.country DESC;


This work for me, hope it helps!
SELECT users.country, SUM(products.price * order_items.quantity) AS total
FROM users
INNER JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user_id
INNER JOIN order_items ON orders.id = order_items.order_id
INNER JOIN products ON order_items.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY users.country
ORDER BY total DESC;


This differs from Ankam's answer only in that it uses full table-names, where Ankam's uses short aliases. Both answers, although they don't explain it, make the valid point that order_items.order_id is unlikely to be the right field to join users.id. Because the asker did not provide table definitions, we do not know whether order_items has a user_id field.

SELECT u.country Country,
       SUM(p.price * oi.quantity) Total_Sales
FROM users u,
     order_items oi,
     products p
WHERE u.id = oi.id
  AND oi.product_id = p.id
ORDER BY Total_Sales ASC;


Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

This code should work:
SELECT
    country
     ,total = SUM(price * oi.quantity)
FROM users u
INNER JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id
INNER JOIN order_items oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
INNER JOIN products p ON oi.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY total DESC;

